# Using a #define to index an array?

Tags: c

This is a stupid question, but I can't work it out and it's beginning to irritate me!

I have the following (reg is a global):

```
#define CS 4
#define DS 5

unsigned char reg[6] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x10};
```

Now, I would expect reg[DS] to access element 5 of array reg (0x10).  However, when debugging (VC2010), Visual Studio is claiming that DS is zero and the first element is accessed.  Is it me, or is Visual Studio being stupid?

Comment: Most likely you, how exactly do you check the value of #define at runtime?

Comment: Did you try to print DS value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

```
reg[DS] == 0x10
```

Unless you have redefined the macro `DS` somewhere else in the code.
Macros are evaluated at pre-compilation. So if you defined `DS` as `5` then what goes to the compiler for compilation is `reg[5]`.

Also, You cannot check a macro value at run-time because they do not exist at run-time, they are already substituted with whatever value they are defined as.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding that `reg[DS]` refers to the fifth (that is, the last) element of `reg` is correct.

If you think that a different element might be getting accessed, I'd make sure that you're not redefining `DS` to a different value else by accident, and that `DS` isn't clashing with a symbol defined by one of the headers that you're including.

Note that `DS` does not exist at run time. Even the compiler does not see get to see `DS`, since it will have been replaced with `5` by the preprocessor. This is what could be tripping up the debugger.